# Too many images!

Tags: discussion, tags

We have 3 quite similar and somewhat ambiguous tags:

[image](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/image), [images](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/images), and [image-processing](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/image-processing).

Only [images](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/images) contains an ounce of info.  But *only* an ounce:

> Questions about opening / editing / saving images using image-editing applications.

Are these tags the same?  Do they need merging?  If not, do they need tag wikis so that people (like me) can *know* that they're not the same?

---

<sup>And while we're at it, here on Meta, [tags](/questions/tagged/tags) and [tagging](/questions/tagged/tagging).</sup>

Answer (score 3):

Both [image](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/image) and [images](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/images) are ambiguous, the tag description is neither helpful. There are at least two meanings that I can think of:

- image in the meaning of "picture" or "photo"
- image in the meaning of "disk-image" (also: firmware images)

I'd drop (blacklist) both the [image](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/image) and [images](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/images) tag and tag these to [picture](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/picture) or [disk-image](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/disk-image). For [image-processing](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/image-processing), it should be clear that this is really about editing pictures and such. The disadvantage is that visitors are likely searching for "image" or "imaging" instead of "disk image" when they mean to write an image to a USB or something. The second solution is to keep the tag, but allow for both meanings, but add extra tags to questions as needed.